# Is there need any "article"?

Tags: meaning, articles, nouns

A: The event has led to **the** creating of the new plan.

B: The event has led to **the** creation of the new plan.

I am wondering if the article **the** is necessary here.

Meanwhile, could you possibly teach me what is the difference between those semantically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A: The event has led to the creating of the new plan.

B: The event has led to the creation of the new plan.

First, the difference between *creating* and *creation*:

*Creating* refers to the activity of creating - not what is created or who is doing the creating.  These questions can be answered with objects to narrow this down - e.g. *him creating the new plan* - in which case you omit the article.

*Creation* can mean this too, but *creation* can also mean *thing that is created*.  *Creating* will never mean *thing that is created.*  Also *creation* is a "real noun"--not a verbal, and won't take objects like an *-ing* word.

In this case there is not a big difference in meaning between these two - but *creating* can give the impression it happened recently if you don't qualify that, and *creation* would give the impression the creating has completed.

So since these are nouns, you follow the usual rules with articles - which are confusing, but if *creating of the new plan* or *creation of the new plan* is an instance of something specified earlier in conversation, or well-known to both parties of the conversation, use *the*.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is incorrect. *The* is an article, which you can combine with a noun (*creation*). Because *creating* is a verb, you cannot combine it with *the*.

So, your second sentence is correct, but your first is not.
Correct would be:

> The event has led to creating the new plan.

Note that you also do not use *of* between *creating* and *the new plan*.

Comment: The last part would be more like "The event has led to the creation of the new plan".  "The shooting has led to the creation of the new gun control law."

Comment: Isn't the first sentence *technically* correct if you interpret the last part as a gerund phrase?

Comment: Hmm, yes I suppose you are right. Technically you could phrase it that way but it does not make much sense. If you're going for an ing-form gerund a better phrasing would be something like this: *The event led to X **creating** the new plan.* However, it does seem to work if you put the gerund phrase in initial position and rephrase slightly: *Creating the new plan is what the event has led to.*

Comment: *-ing* words are not full verbs unless preceded by a form of the word *to be*, e.g. *am going*, *are leaving*, *have been moving*.  Otherwise they are participles or gerunds.

Comment: I'm with @CrazyEyes. The gerund is grammatically correct but sounds awful because *creation* is such an easy substitute. Cf. ```My melancholy led to my unfriending of about 200 people on Facebook.``` Sounds somewhat OK (although I would still prefer *led to my unfriending about 200 people*). I'm arguing the first sentence I concocted sounds OK because *unfriending* doesn't have a clear alternative noun form, probably because it didn't come from Latin. :)

Comment: The killing of the trolls, the bringing of gifts is discouraged, the smoking of cigarettes is forbidden, the eating of fruit is ... . Hmm, we seem to be able to feely make a noun out of a verb by adding an  *-ing* ending.

Comment: @CrazyEyes It isn't a gerund. A gerund is a verb. This is a noun. They look the same but the grammar is different.

Comment: @CrazyEyes Although you're right that it's grammatical, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> A: This event led to **the** creating of the new plan.
>
> B: This event led to **the** creation of the new plan.

***The***

When we use this type of *of* phrase in this way to modify a noun, the larger noun phrase will normally take a definite article. Notice that the purpose of the phrase *of the new plan* is to show us *which* creation we are talking about. Because we understand *which* creation the speaker is talking about, they need to use a definite article here.

***Creating*** and ***Creation***

We can make a noun from a verb by adding *-ing* to the plain form of the verb:

- smoke --> The smoking of cigarettes
- sink --> The sinking of the submarine
- fly --> The flying of the Irish flag

Notice that nouns cannot take Direct Objects, so the things that were smoked or sunk or flown are described in a preposition phrase, using the preposition *of*.

These look like *-ing* forms of a verb, sometimes called gerunds or participles. They are not! They are nouns not verbs. We cannot use articles (the, a) with verbs either, but these nouns use articles just like other nouns.

Sometimes we already have a noun to describe an action. When there is already a noun we can use, if we use a special *-ing* noun, it can sound unusual (maybe in a good way).

Here there is already a noun we can use, *creation*. There is not *very* much difference in meaning between the two words *creating* and *creation*. In my opinion using the noun *creating* here puts more emphasis on the time or work needed to create the plan. It brings out the human involvement in the creation of the plan. But that's just my feeling.

Both sentences are perfectly fine and grammatical.